Do I need to perform RAID re-sync separately from each operating system?
I previously had two hard drives: one accessed from Windows (Disk D) that has NTFS filesystem and is BitLocker encrypted, and another with a Linux system using LUKS+LVM. The second disk also had a different Linux system with LUKS+LVM.
I bought 2 Hard Disks.
I changed the BIOS settings from AHCI to RAID mode, created a new RAID 1 mirror with these two new hard drives migrated all data from old disks using Clonezilla's DD mode. As I understand that this is a software RAID. Upon booting into my Debian system, I saw that it started an mdadm re-sync process, which I assume will happen periodically.
Both Linux systems are encrypted with LUKS, and Disk D is encrypted with BitLocker. As a result, when I boot into one Linux system, I cannot see the other Linux system or access Disk D until I mount them.
My question is: Do I need to perform the re-sync from each Linux system separately, and then separately from Windows? Or is it sufficient to perform the re-sync from one system to ensure that everything is synchronized?
Thank you for your assistance!
